# Add a variable to a javascript email

Tags: javascript, html, email, hyperlink

How would I add var bob to the body of this email?

```
var bob;
function sendMail() {
var link = "mailto:YourEmailHere"
         + "?cc="
         + "&subject=App Build Link Buit With MWFPRO's App Build Tool"
         + "&body=Hi" 
;

window.location.href = link;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var name = "Bob";
function sendMail() {
var link = "mailto:YourEmailHere"
     + "?cc="
     + "&subject=App Build Link Buit With MWFPRO's App Build Tool"
     + "&body=Hi " + name + ","; 
;
```